GRUB problem after Windows 11 24H2 update
On my laptop I have Ubuntu 24.04.1 and Windows 11. After updating Windows 11 to version 24H2 and after rebooting, GRUB (2.12) no longer loads normally with the OS selection, but I have a GRUB screen in the  terminal that says:
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. 
For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions.
Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions. 
To enable less(1)-like paging, "set pager=1"

With the command ls -la it sees:
   Partition hd0,gpt3: Filesystem type ntfs (Windows 11)
   Partition hd0,gpt2: Filesystem type ext* (Ubuntu)
   Partition hd0,gpt1: Filesystem type fat
[
Boot-Repair:
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,2)/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    offsetio extcmd macho elf file gettext boot bufio verifiers crypto 
    terminal normal datetime date mmap drivemap blocklist archelp newc 
    vga_text relocator video chain ntldr search_label search_fs_file 
    search_fs_uuid search keylayouts at_keyboard pci usb usb_keyboard gcry_md5 
    hashsum gcry_crc gzio xzio lzopio lspci fshelp ext2 xfs acpi reboot 
    iso9660 gcry_sha1 div udf exfat font diskfilter raid6rec zstd btrfs ventoy 
    read halt video_fb vbe linux linux16 test true sleep echo bitmap gfxterm 
    bitmap_scale trig video_colors gfxmenu videotest videoinfo functional_test 
    videotest_checksum video_cirrus video_bochs vga minicmd help configfile tr 
    biosdisk disk ls tar zfs squash4 pbkdf2 gcry_sha512 password_pbkdf2 
    all_video png jpeg part_gpt part_msdos fat ntfs loopback 
    gfxterm_background procfs gfxterm_menu smbios
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       exfat
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/sda1: /dev/sda1 already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda2 and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F8CN59WW(V2.22)(2.59) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 2002,2001,0000,2003,0004
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,ae8e9f69-616a-4ce9-88af-11a0580d9d07,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi) File(.䍒)
Boot0001* EFI USB Device (KingstonDataTraveler 3.0) UsbWwid(951,1666,0,E0D55EA573E9E6A0B857109)/HD(2,MBR,0x28769d89,0x735b000,0x10000)RC
Boot0002* EFI PXE 0 for IPv4 (7C-8A-E1-74-90-69)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(7c8ae1749069,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0003* EFI PXE 0 for IPv6 (7C-8A-E1-74-90-69)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(7c8ae1749069,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,ae8e9f69-616a-4ce9-88af-11a0580d9d07,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000033000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, exfat

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: CA9BC4BC-3BE5-424B-A0CF-6A42132FF430
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048    2203647    2201600     1G EFI System
nvme0n1p2    2203648    6498303    4294656     2G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p3    6498304  417523711  411025408   196G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p4  417523712 1951420415 1533896704 731.4G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p5 1951420416 1953521663    2101248     1G Windows recovery environment
Disk sda: 57.71 GiB, 61964550144 bytes, 121024512 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x28769d89
     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *         2048 120958975 120956928 57.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2       120958976 121024511     65536   32M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
Disk mapper/ventoy: 5.78 GiB, 6203355136 bytes, 12115928 sectors
Disk identifier: EED3DE8A-ACD3-4541-BA15-9014C007D874
                      Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
mapper/ventoy-part1       64 12105119 12105056  5.8G Microsoft basic data
mapper/ventoy-part2 12105120 12115263    10144    5M EFI System
mapper/ventoy-part3 12115264 12115863      600  300K Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:62.0GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Kingston DataTraveler 3.0:;
1:1049kB:61.9GB:61.9GB:::boot;
2:61.9GB:62.0GB:33.6MB:fat16::esp;
mapper/ventoy:6203MB:dm:512:512:gpt:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:32.8kB:6198MB:6198MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:6198MB:6203MB:5194kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:6203MB:6203MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
nvme0n1:1000GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:KINGSTON SNV2S1000G:;
1:1049kB:1128MB:1127MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:1128MB:3327MB:2199MB:ext4:Basic data partition:msftdata;
3:3327MB:214GB:210GB:ext4::;
4:214GB:999GB:785GB:ntfs:Windows 11:msftdata;
5:999GB:1000GB:1076MB:ntfs::hidden, diag, no_automount;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME       FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                  
├─sda1     exfat    20CA-144C                            28769d89-01                          Ventoy 
│ └─ventoy                                                                                           
└─sda2                                                                                               
nvme0n1                                                                                              

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                       Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ventoy         0 100% /cdrom
efivarfs               32.3K  80% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/mapper/ventoy     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
ventoy

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on nvme0n1p1

Unknown BootLoader on nvme0n1p2

Unknown BootLoader on nvme0n1p3


================================= User choice ==================================

Is there RAID on this computer? no

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.


Grub runs, but can't find it's grub.cfg file. Nothing in Windows11 24h2 should cause this problem (been running it for months dual boot). Is there more than one stub grub.cfg (look in .../EFI/Boot and .../EFI/ubuntu).  The Ubuntu root UUID ends in ...8da01 -- does the grub.cfg file have that UUID in it?  If you just force the load of the maintained grub.cfg file, (configfile (hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg) do you get the menu?   Pleease add requested information to your original posting, not inn comments.

Sorry cannot use original message, I'm using the comments: do you see my photo attached? I can only have access to the GRUB cli (terminal), how can I look into (.../EFI/Boot and .../EFI/ubuntu) from there? thanks

the problem is, maybe I didn't write it, that it doesn't load Ubuntu anymore but only GRUB and it remains in that screen with the GRUB terminal.

The EFI partition from your picture is (hd0,gpt1), so use ls (hd0,gpt1)/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg to see if it exists, and cat (hd0,gp1)/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg to examine it (it's only a few lines long).

the answer to ls (hd0,gpt1)/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg is: grub.cfg

the answer to cat (hd0,gp1)/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg is: search.fs_uuid4ebd4441-f48b-4946-85a7-f5a4f9012495 root; set prefix=($root) '/boot/grub'; configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

I also have the result from the boot-reapir test: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6NTg9YDry6/

there is no grub.cfg in ls (hd0,gpt1)/EFI/boot/grub.cfg

The Ubuntu root UUID ends in ...8da01, my UUID 4ebd4441-f48b-4946-85a7-f5a4f9012495 does not end in 8da01

I did configfile (hd0,gpt1)/boot/grub/grub.cfg and I did not get the menu, I've got another clean CLI (terminal) with grub> only there. (sorry ubfan1 for the many comments)

gpt2 is your root partition, so try:   configfile (hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg

configfile (hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg is not working, I've got another clean CLI (terminal) with grub> only there.

have you seen this?  paste.ubuntu.com/p/6NTg9YDry6

From that link, looks like gpt3 is the ubuntu install (based on size alone).  However, no filesystems at all are discovered on the nvme drive (no UUID found at all).  Logical volumes and encryption are beyond my area of knowledge. At the grub prompt, the tab will show the valid choices, check them all: elgl ls (hd0,  TAB  to show the gpt partitions, choose one , type the closing ")/" and TAB again to show directories, etc.)

first of all I want to thank you for your assistance, I've launched 'MiniTool Partition Wizard Technician' from boot, the Windows 11 24H2 update has cancelled Ubuntu data partition; can they do that? This is the reason why GRUB was not working anymore, Ubuntu was not there anymore! I'd like to really know if Microsoft can (legally) do that, I had already Windows 11 23H2 installed and I told the OS to make an upgrade to 24H2, they cancelled Ubuntu that was on the same HDD during the update, unbelievable! Thank you for your help.

You can answer your own question, and after awhile, accept it, helping others and gaining some reputation points. I was wrong earlier, my 24h2 was only running in a VM, not dual boot -- guess I'd better be fully backed up before I allow the actual dual boot Windows to update from 23h2.

You know what? I've installed a second M.2 on laptop, installed there Ubuntu and GRUB saw it immediately and everything is now back where it was; in my opinion (personal opinion) this is not totally legal, I think Linux has the 4.45% of the market right now, so it's a small market but really important, the others are big and overbearing.
